# How to get rails_blob_url for the avatar attached to User Model from Userspublication?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :userspublications
  has_one_attached :avatar
end
```

```
class Userspublication < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_one_attached :post
end
```

How do i access avatar(rails_blob_url) from Userspublication i have this following query?

This is what i have tried

```
Userspublication.joins(:user)
.joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN followers ON followers.user_id=users.id 
        Left Outer join active_storage_attachments 
        ON active_storage_attachments.record_id = users.id 
        AND active_storage_attachments.record_type = 'User' 
        AND active_storage_attachments.name = 'avatar'
        where followers.followeduser_id = 3 or users.id = 3").select("users.first_name,users.last_name,active_storage_attachments.record_type as 'avatar',userspublications.*").order(updated_at: :desc)
```

Comment: whoever down voted this question. Can you please tell me whats wrong so i can be correct the next time. Just by down voting without saying anything wont help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for the help guys (specially @arieljuod) i figured out the answer it was pretty simple :

```
return rails_blob_path(object.user.avatar, only_path: true)
```

Here object is of Userspublication!

(The guy who down voted this question if you cant answer and can't even bother to help in understanding whats wrong with it "suck it"!!)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the field `blob_id` from the `active_storage_attachments` table and then use it to get the Blob with `blob = ActiveStorage::Blob.find(blob_id)`. And then you can call `url_for(blob)`.