# Why rails_blob_url in the application and in the test works generates different links?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec-rails, active-model-serializers, blobstorage, url-helper

In ReviewsController serializers are used to display json. Like here:

```
 render json: @reviews, each_serializer: ReviewSerializer, root: false
```

The serializer uses the following attribute **:image**. Like this:

```
class ReviewSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :image          
  include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers

  def image
    rails_blob_url(object.image) if object.image.attached?
  end
end
```

A helper '**rails_blob_url**' is used here.

The same helper is used in the spec_test. Like here:

```
run_test! do
  expect(response_body).to eq([{ id:   review.id,
                                image: rails_blob_url(review.image) }])
end
```

When running the test, the links to the image do not match

```
:image=>
    - "http://www.example.com/rails/active_storage/blobs/redirect/ey.../test_image.jpg"
    + "http://localhost/rails/active_storage/blobs/redirect/ey.../test_image.jpg"
```

Do you know what the problem might be? And how to fix it?

P.S.:
I read this
[How to get rails_blob_url for the avatar attached to User Model from Userspublication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56103240/how-to-get-rails-blob-url-for-the-avatar-attached-to-user-model-from-userspublic)

and this
[rails_blob_path host: and only_path: true returns the same?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56103240/how-to-get-rails-blob-url-for-the-avatar-attached-to-user-model-from-userspublic),
but I didn't find the answer there

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the host in url options. For tests, add

```
Rails.application.routes.default_url_options[:host] = 'localhost:3000'
```

to `config/environments/test.rb`

Failing that, try setting `ActiveStorage::Current.host = "http://localhost:3000"` before running the specs.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it didn't help (

Comment: Specified the default option. 
Like here:
`Rails.application.configure do`
 `--//-- `
 end

Rails.application.routes.default_url_options[:host] = 'localhost:3000'`

And I tried it.
`ActiveStorage::Current.host = "http://localhost:3000"`
Before
 `run_test! do`
  response_body).to eq([{ id:   review.id,
                              image: rails_blob_url(review.image) }])
 end`
So far, I've only managed to come up with a temporary solution.
In the test:
`image: rails_blob_url(media_review.image, host: "https://localhost")`

But I would still like to solve the problem globally.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was solved when I updated docker-compose to version 2.3.4